# Setting drop-down list validation by VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, validation, excel-2013, vba

I've got a VBA macro to copy two sheets (one a form to collect data, one a sheet with a batch of lookups for the drop-down menus) from a main workbook, populate the new workbook and save it out.

Because the drop-down data validation lists update their links when the sheet is copied, I have to reset the validation to refer to the new `Lookups` sheet. At the moment, I'm trying this (with varying coordinates, of course):

```
With wsNew.Cells(19, 5)  ' Display on web schedule
    .Value = wsData.Cells(11, iColCount).Value
    .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lookups!$B$2:$B$3"
    .Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
    .Validation.InCellDropdown = True
End With
```

As soon as it gets to the `.Validation.Add Type...` line, it breaks with a 1004 ("Application-defined or object-defined error") error.

**If there's any way to copy the sheet without it automatically updating the data validation** that would be the ideal, but if there isn't, does anyone know what's causing that code to break and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete any prior data validation before attempting to create a new one.

```
With wsNew.Cells(19, 5)  ' Display on web schedule
    .Value = wsData.Cells(11, iColCount).Value
    .Validation.DELETE
    .Validation.Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween, Formula1:="=Lookups!$B$2:$B$3"
    .Validation.IgnoreBlank = True
    .Validation.InCellDropdown = True
End With
```